# How to terminate node.js http request if size is too large?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

I want to terminate an http server in node.js process if the user's request is larger than 8mb. My current code appears to work in basic testing but I'm not sure if res.end() is async and could be destroyed before completion by process.exit(). I used process.exit here because if the user's request is larger than 8mb I don't want to have to keep the process alive while they send large amounts of data.

```
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
    if(body.length > 8000000) {
        res.writeHead(413, defaultHead);
        res.end('{"error":"Request exceeded 8mb maximum size."}');
        process.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing, it will work because same thing is done by `body-parser` the popular package for parsing `req.body` in express.

Now, How `body-parser` does is, it uses another package called `raw-body`, which takes a `limit` parameter and if the current chunk > limit it calls the callback that is passed.

```
  function onData (chunk) {
    if (complete) return

    received += chunk.length

    if (limit !== null && received > limit) {
      done(createError(413, 'request entity too large', {
        limit: limit,
        received: received,
        type: 'entity.too.large'
      }))
    } else if (decoder) {
      buffer += decoder.write(chunk)
    } else {
      buffer.push(chunk)
    }
  }
```

`done` is the callback here, and it creates an error and pushes it as the first param in the callback.

In the `body-parser` code:

```
getBody(stream, opts, function (error, body) {
  if (error) {
    var _error= createError(400, error)

    // read off entire request
    stream.resume()
    onFinished(req, function onfinished () {
      next(createError(400, _error))
    })
    return
  }

  ....
  next()
})
```

In case of error, It just reads off the entire stream using `stream.resume()` and passes the error. So basically you are replicating a simple version of this, which in theory should work.

Note, `onFinished` is another package which Execute a callback when a HTTP request closes, finishes, or errors.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. To keep things simple I would like to just stick with process.exit unless there really could be a problem closing the connection. You talked about that onFinished package but do you really think it's needed or is process.exit ok?

Comment: No i dont think it is needed. You can probably can also throw an error there. instead of process exit. But exiting the process will in turn close every pipe and stream. so you are good to go.