# How to log when limit is exceeded when using express.json({limit: 1500000})?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I log when the size limit is exceeded before express sends a response? Im using this as middleware:`

```
app.use(express.json({limit: 1500000}));
```

I would like to have a chance to use my logger (or just a simple console.log) when a request body exceeds the 1.5mb limit. Do you know how I could do this?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found that a global error handler middleware can catch the error thrown by app.use(express.json({limit: 1500000})); and that the log could be done after the error is caught.

Another approach could be to log inside this code before ending:

```
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
    if(body.length > 8000000) {
        res.writeHead(413, defaultHead);
        res.end('{"error":"Request exceeded 8mb maximum size."}');
        process.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Like described in this answer:
[How to terminate node.js http request if size is too large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484115/how-to-terminate-node-js-http-request-if-size-is-too-large)

Answer (score 0):

you can use middleware like this -

```
const logBodySize = (req, res, next) => {
  const contentLength = req.headers['content-length'];

  if (contentLength && parseInt(contentLength) > 1500000) {
    logger(`Request body size exceeded the limit: ${contentLength} bytes`);
  }

  next();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This method will not stop the request data transfer if it exceeds the limit. So a lot of data could be transfered beyond the limit.